# Class member suddenly becomes inaccessible/non-existent

Tags: c++, class, memory, destructor

In my main, I am calling a function (`func1`)in a loop. This function is a member of `Class1`. I am passing an object (`object2`) of a different class, `Class2` to this function. On the first iteration of the loop, the variable `var2` (member of `Class2`) is accessible from main, but on the second iteration, it is not. I get an "Access violation reading location" error. Here is what my code looks like:

main.cpp:

```
#include "Class1.h"
int main(){

    Class2 object2;
    object2.assign_var2();
    Class1 object1;


    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        std::cout << object2.var[0][0][0] << std::endl; // Works ONLY on first iteration
        object1.func1(object2)
    }
}
```

Class2.h:

```
class Class2{
    ... other variables and functions declared
    public:
    Class2::Class2();
    Class2::~Class2();
    double *** var2;
    void assign_var2();
}
```

Class2.cpp:

```
Class2::Class2(){

var2 = new double**[200];
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    var2[i] = new double*[200];

    for (int j = 0; j < 200; ++j){
    var2[i][j] = new double[2];
    }
}

Class2::~Class2(){
for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 200; ++j){
        delete [] var2[i][j];
    }
    delete [] var2[i];
}
delete [] var2;
}

void assign_var2(){
for (int i = 0; i<200; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j<200; ++j){

        var2[i][j][0] = some_number1;
        var2[i][j][1] = some_number2;
    }
}
}
}
```

Class1.h:

```
#include "Class2.h"
class Class1{
    ... other variables, functions declared
    public:
    void func1(Class2)
```

}

Class1.cpp:

```
Class1::func1(Class2 object2){
    int u = object2.var2[1][2][0];
    int v = object2.var2[1][2][1];
}
```

Side note: If I try and print a different variable instead of `var2`, it seems to work on the second iteration, so I don't think it's a problem with the object itself.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which anomalies did you observe, when stepping through your code with a decent debugger? Most probably you're accessing unallocated memory, or trying to access out of array bounds.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I checked for out of array bounds and it's not that... it seems like I'm trying to access memory that no longer exists, but I don't know how that happened. Like I said, it works on the first iteration of the loop, but not the second. And I'm attempting to access the same memory location in both instances.

Comment: run it under valgrind

Comment: Why don't you use nested vectors instead of manually allocating memory?

Comment: @awilds _"Like I said, it works on the first iteration of the loop"_ That smells like you're hitting undefined behavior in 1st place.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Class1::func1(Class2 object2)` accepts the argument by value. This means that a copy of the `Class2` object is being made, and then destructed when `func1()` returns.

In the `Class2` class you do not define a copy constructor, so the compiler is creating one for you that simply copies the members by-value.  Then when the copy's destructor runs, it `delete`s all of the allocations, leaving the original object with a pointer to an invalid object.  This is why it fails on the second iteration.

Always follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)): if you need a custom destructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment operator, *you need all three of them*. A proper copy constructor will create new allocations for all of the arrays and copy the data to them. (If you are using C++11 then it's actually the *rule of five*: you probably also want to implement a move constructor and move assignment operator so that you can "steal" the `var2` pointer in cases where you know that the object being assigned is an rvalue and therefore will be going away soon anyway.)

In your case, the fix is simple: accept the argument by reference:

```
Class1::func1(Class2 const & object2)
```

I would strongly suggest using `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>` for your `var2` member instead, because then the compiler-generated destructor, copy-constructor, and copy-assignment operator will all do the right thing, and you won't need to implement any of them.

This works hand-in-hand with making `func1()` accept a reference: while the error is happening because there isn't a custom copy constructor, we really don't even want to make a copy here because we're not modifying the data.  Copying the data only to destroy the copy is silly; let's just accept a reference to an existing object instead of requiring a superfluous copy.

Alternatively, you can just disable copying altogether:

```
class Class2 {
    // ...

    // For C++11: explicitly delete the copy-ctor and copy-assignment operator.
public:
    Class2(Class2 const &) = delete;
    Class2 & operator=(Class2 const &) = delete;

    // For C++03: declare the copy-ctor and copy-assignment operator private and
    // then do not implement them. (C++03 doesn't have the "= delete" syntax.)
private:
    Class2(Class2 const &);
    Class2 & operator=(Class2 const &);
```

If you disable copying then you would get a compile-time error on the call `object1.func1(object2)` because it depends on the existence of a copy-constructor for `object2`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It makes sense... but then why am I able to access other members of `Class2`, but `var2` fails?

Comment: @awilds Because the other members are not affected by the copy, presumably. `var2` only fails because the copy deallocated the same allocations that the original object points to.